# Pandas create dataframe with day by day column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe as below:

```
Item_name | Start_date | Due_date | Value
Item 1      1/1/20       15/1/20    10
Item 1      7/1/20       29/2/20    15
```

I wanna calculate a new Dataframe from it, with the column is the date by date from the range between start_date and due_date, and value of each date column is sum of column value in this date as below:

```
Item_name | 1/1/20 | 2/1/20 | ... | 7/1/20 | ... | 15/1/20 | 16/1/20 | ... | 28/2/20 | 29/2/20
Item 1      10       10             25             25        15              15       15
```

(from 1/1/20 to 6/1/20, value of Item 1 is 10 only, from 7/1/20 to 15/1/20, the total value day by day is 10 + 15)

How can I create it efficiently?

Comment: So you want the day by day total to be calculated over all rows, regardless of the item number?  Seems like item 2 gets summed  with item 1?

Comment: Sorry I have edited the typo. It is both Item 1. It should be grouped by item name.

Comment: Whats the logic behind the value after the date `15/1/20`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, on 15 january both items exist, so it is 10+15 the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is to build the date range manually and explode, then we can group by date and item:

```
(df.set_index(['Item_name', 'Value'])
   .assign(date_range=lambda x: [pd.date_range(s,d, freq='D') 
                                     for s,d in zip(x.Start_date, x.Due_date)])
   ['date_range'].explode()
  .reset_index()
  .groupby(['Item_name','date_range'])['Value']
  .sum()
  .unstack()
)
```

Output:

```
date_range  2020-01-01  2020-01-02  2020-01-03  2020-01-04  2020-01-05  \
Item_name                                                                
Item 1              10          10          10          10          10   

date_range  2020-01-06  2020-01-07  2020-01-08  2020-01-09  2020-01-10  ...  \
Item_name                                                               ...   
Item 1              10          25          25          25          25  ...   

date_range  2020-02-20  2020-02-21  2020-02-22  2020-02-23  2020-02-24  \
Item_name                                                                
Item 1              15          15          15          15          15   

date_range  2020-02-25  2020-02-26  2020-02-27  2020-02-28  2020-02-29  
Item_name                                                               
Item 1              15          15          15          15          15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get to your desired output with below self explained code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

# Create DataFrame and format datetime to columns Start_date and Due_date
df = pd.DataFrame(\
[["Item 1","1/1/20","15/1/20",10],\
["Item 1","7/1/20","29/2/20",15]],\
columns=["Item_name","Start_date","Due_date","Value"])
df["Start_date"] =  pd.to_datetime(df["Start_date"], format="%d/%m/%y")
df["Due_date"] =  pd.to_datetime(df["Due_date"], format="%d/%m/%y")

# Function to create the date range series
def createDateRange(row):
    return pd.date_range(row["Start_date"],row["Due_date"],freq='d')

# Apply function to create Date ranges for all Items
df["dates"] = df.apply(createDateRange, axis=1)
# Explode dates and groupby dates and sum the values
df = df.explode("dates").groupby(["dates"])["Value"].sum()
#And finally you can arrange your data within a dataframe and transpose it
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.columns=(["Item 1"])
df = df.transpose()
```

And the result is:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
dates   2020-01-01  2020-01-02  2020-01-03  2020-01-04  2020-01-05  2020-01-06  2020-01-07  ...  2020-02-23  2020-02-24  2020-02-25  2020-02-26  2020-02-27  2020-02-28  2020-02-29
Item 1          10          10          10          10          10          10          25  ...          15          15          15          15          15          15          15

[1 rows x 60 columns]
```

Comment: You should take into account that `explode` function was introduced to `pandas` in version `0.25.0`.